# Digispark Micro (ATTINY85) not working on Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: attiny, mac-os, attiny85, digispark

I just bought 2 Digispark Micro to start learning some Arduino things.

But when I try to upload the code to my Digispark, it just send me an "Device search timed out" error.

My Digispark is plugged with an USB-C to USB connector and the Red dot on the Digispark is working. The connector is working well with any other device.

**Arduino app (1.8.9) settings:**

- Tools

  - Board → Digispark (Default - 16.5 mhz)
  - Programmer → Micronucleus

I tried using the [micronucleus CLI](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/tree/master/commandline), but, even if I try plug/unplug several times (~10s between each unplug/plug) I got this :

```
> Please plug in the device ...
> Press CTRL+C to terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 3):

Digisparks are known to have problems with USB3 ports (which your USB-C adaptor probably provides). Try using a cheap USB2 hub between the DigiSpark and the adaptor.

It's always a good idea to use a cheap USB hub between whatever experimental device you want to connect and your machine, so that if you wire something up incorrectly you don't end up frying an expensive laptop. This is particularly true for a device such as the digispark which does not have a real USB interface but really bit-bangs the protocol out of ordinary I/O pins.

There is no guarantee that the hub will protect you from all wiring mistakes, but it's an added level of protection.

Comment: Hi @JayEye ! Thanks for those information. I'm already using this device (https://www.apple.com/fr/shop/product/MJ1M2ZM/A/adaptateur-usb-c-vers-usb?afid=p238%7Cs4VqawkmI-dc_mtid_187079nc38483_pcrid_102671600198_&cid=aos-fr-kwgo-pla-btb--slid-----product-MJ1M2ZM/A-FR). Isn't it enoough?

Comment: Good thing I speak French :)

No, this will not be enough; this just converts the physical connector (USB-C to USB-A). You need something like https://www.amazon.com/Black-4-Port-High-Speed-USB/dp/B002FFT8Z6 between the adaptor you have and the digispark